# How to get the variable value from variable list in unix?

Tags: list, shell, variables, unix, readfile

I have severial variables with prefix INPUT:

```
${INPUT_1:="sample.txt"}
${INPUT_2:="sample_2.txt"}
${INPUT_3:="sample_3.txt"}
```

And then I get a list of variable value with prefix INPUT by :

```
env | awk -F= '/^INPUT/ {print $2}'
```

the result:

**sample.txt
sample_2.txt
sample_3.txt**

And then I want to count the lines of each these three file, I tried

```
 var = env | awk -F= '/^INPUT/ {print $2}'
 wc -l $var
```

But it didn' work.
Does someone could help me with applying **wc -l**  on the variables selected?

Comment: https://shellcheck.net . but also research `xargs`, many, many Q/A here for that topic. Good luck.

Comment: That's really a good website, thank U !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way looks like this I guess :

```
for input in $var
do 
  wc -l $input
done
```

Comment: Thanks .I tried it, while it didn't work, and no error message is shown, I wonder if it is because that  it concerns file not normal variables of strings

Comment: the script must be run in the same directory of files that will "counted".

Comment: All the code is in a shell script, and I put the for loop at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks YLR, it works, I had some syntax errors, thanks a lot!